# use non-default overloaded operator in smlnj

Tags: sml, smlnj

smlnj will make overloaded operator, like op + to use int by default, now I want to it returns a function in real * real -> real, how can I do in inline way?

"inline way" means not something like binding a new val:

```
fun add(x:real,y:real) = x + y;
```

If my memory is correct there is some grammar allows sml it to just do something like "cast" op + to real, but I can't really find it anywhere..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various ways that you can get SML to type `op+` as the real counterpart.

Depending on what ever code you have,

- You can as suggested, type annotate the surrounding function, thus enforcing the parameters to `op+` to be of type real.
- Since you are nonfixing the addition function (presumably for use as a higher order function?), you could just as well pass along the addition function from the real module `Real.+`
- Or you could annotate it like this: `op+ : real * real -> real`, which is really ugly and stupid, considering you can use `Real.+` instead. But it is an option.

Answer (score 0):

If the default instance of the operator is not the one you need for your value's type, you can use type annotation on the operands to enforce the desired typing.

For example, while

```
val f = fn a => a + a
```

will be typed `int -> int`, this value

```
val g = fn a:real => a + a
```

will be typed `real -> real`.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare

```
open Real
```

in the scope where you define the function, but I strongly advise against that. Type-annotating the function is the best way. You don't have to annotate every parameter, btw, it's enough to do one, or in this case, even the return type:

```
fun add(x : real, y) = x + y

fun add(x, y) : real = x + y
```